# Default I18n ActiveRecord validation translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

Can I use a default I18n config for lookups if localisation file lookup fails?

As part of Rails, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#how-i18n-in-ruby-on-rails-works

> As part of this solution, every static string in the Rails framework — e.g. Active Record validation messages, time and date formats — has been internationalized, so localization of a Rails application means “over-riding” these defaults.

So, when I add my own localisation files, I lose the default rails error text for ActiveRecord.
e.g. given the following code within a Model

```
validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 50
```

When this fails, I get

```
translation missing: en-gb, activerecord, errors, models, model_name, attributes, name, too_long
```

Two possible fixes :

1. Add `:message` to each and every `validates_*` method? e.g.

   ```
   validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 50, :message => "is too long (maximum is %{count} characters)"
   ```

   The problem with this is there are quite a few calls, and people adding new code would have to have remember to add the text.
   (And I dont think variable substitution works here!)
2. Add the set of defaults that [rails uses](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml) in each and every locale config file, e.g

   ```
   errors:
     messages:
       less_than: must be less than %{count}
   ```

   The problem here is that the same text has to be added to every locale file (as I am not interested in translating these), this is not that big off a deal, but seems odd.

Which, if any, routes are advised? Any other ideas or suggestions?

Is there no default/fallback file that the I18n uses, i.e. if the lookup cannot be found in the locale file?

(Using rails 2.3.5)

Answer (score 2):

I find the best thing here is to just include the [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem in your project so that you have translations in all available locales. And then in your application's translation files, just override the ones you need.

Note : You'll need your project to use the same locales as defined by the gem, so in your example you'd want to use `en-GB` rather than `en-gb`.